# My ngTable with groups doesn't works

Tags: angularjs, grouping, ngtable

Good morning,

I'm trying to build a table with groups using AngularJS and ngTable:

HTML

```
<table ng-table="tableParams" show-filter="true" class="table table-hover">
    <colgroup>
        <col />
        <col />
        <col />
    </colgroup>
   <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Name
            </th>
            <th>
                Surname
            </th>
            <th>
                Age
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="group in $data" class="ng-table-group">
            <td colspan="3">
                <a href="" ng-click="group.$hideRows = !group.$hideRows">
                    <strong>Request Id {{ group.RequestId }}</strong>
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-hide="group.$hideRows" ng-repeat="person in $data.people">
            <td sortable="'RequestId'" data-title="'RequestId'" ng-if="false">
                {{group.RequestId}}
            </td>
            <td sortable="'Name'" data-title="'Name'">
                {{person.Name}}
            </td>
            <td sortable="'Surname'" data-title="'Surname'">
                {{person.Surname}}
            </td>
            <td sortable="'Age'" data-title="'Age'">
                {{person.Age}}
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I don't have `ng-app` and `ng-controller` becouse the page is and Angular view so there are in the main view.

Controller

```
myApp.controller('myController', function ($scope, $rootScope, $WebService, ngTableParams) {
    $scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams({}, {
        group: 'RequestId',
        counts: [],
        getData: function ($defer, params) {
            var promise = $WebService.getPersons($scope);

            promise.then(function (results) {

                $defer.resolve(results.data);

            }, function (data, status, headers, config) {
                alert('There was an error while loading the requested data.');
            });
        }
    });
});
```

The json that I get from web service looks like this:

```
[
   {
      "RequestId":11,
      "people":[
        {
            "Name":"James",
            "Surname":"Doo",
            "Age":20
        },
        {
            "Name":"John",
            "Surname":"Doo",
            "Age":20
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "RequestId":12,
      "people":[
        {
            "Name":"Mary",
            "Surname":"Doo",
            "Age":20
        },
        {
            "Name":"Jane",
            "Surname":"Doo",
            "Age":20
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

I worked following this [example](http://codepen.io/christianacca/pen/ojvGaN) and the result is that the table shows with the link `Request Id ...` but when I click it the Group doesn't shows.
I've not errors in the console, simply nothing happens.

I can see the different widths of the header columns so I suppose that the data are correctly loaded.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you

Comment: You are using secure `rawgit` URL. On Chrome, I am getting the connection refused error. Try switching to `http` instead.

Comment: What do you mean? I don't undestand

Comment: You have referenced `ngTable` JS and CSS file using `https` protocol. On my browser I got the error `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT` for url [https://rawgit.com/esvit/ng-table/master/dist/ng-table.min.js](https://rawgit.com/esvit/ng-table/master/dist/ng-table.min.js) . Switching to `http` is just one step toward resolving the issue.